# firestore find the next 20 docs for each page?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how to firestore find the next 20 docs for each page for each query?
examples I am on the 3rd page I need docs from 20-30 from `.orderBy("created_on", "desc")`

```
await FS.collection(FSName.product)
.orderBy("created_on", "desc")
.limit(10)
.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cursors for Pagination.

See

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#web
- https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/f003ef8c725f0039215badc00f888c41620bb8d2/firestore/test.firestore.js#L944

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `startAt()` or `startAfter()` methods to set a starting point in the query and the `endAt()` or `endBefore()` methods to set an ending point:

```
db.collection("product")
  .orderBy("created_on", "desc")
  .startAt(20)
  .endAt(30)
```

You can also use the `limit()` method along with `startAfter()`:

```
db.collection("product")
  .orderBy("created_on", "desc")
  .startAfter(lastVisible)
  .limit(10);
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) is the Firebase documentation for this